# Dúvida [PROBLEMA DE MÉDIA]

Tags: c

Faça um programa em C que receba uma sequência de números naturais e exiba todos os elementos
que são maiores que a média aritmética desta sequência. Caso não haja elementos maiores que a média, deve ser impresso em uma única linha o número 0.

Meu código:

```
       #include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int N, i, qtde = 0;
signed long int valores[10000];
float media = 0;
scanf("%d", &N);
for(i = 0; i < N; i++){
    scanf("%li", &valores[i]);
    media += valores[i];
}

for(i = 0; i < N; i++){


        if( (media/N) <  valores[i] ){
            printf("%li ", valores[i]);
            qtde++;
        }

}
if(qtde == 0)
    printf("0\n");
return 0;
```

}

O juiz eletrônico acusa "Wrong Answer". Alguma ideia do porquê?

Comment: Bom, a lógica parece correta. Poderia colocar aqui o enunciado do problema?

Comment: https://moj.naquadah.com.br/contests/jl_eda1a_a2_2020_0/vetor8.pdf

Comment: Talvez seja problema na formatação da saída, já que o problema diz explicitamente que na saída os números devem ser separados por espaço, porém não deve ter espaço após o último número da saída.

Comment: Note que a questão diz: "Considere também que x̄ é um número inteiro." mas você declarou media como float. É aconselhável calcular `media /= N;` uma única vez logo o primeiro loop e utilizar tal media nas comparações. Veja também a observação de G. Bittencourt, que pode ser feita da seguinte forma: `printf("%li%s", valores[i], (i<N) ? " " : "");`.

Answer (score 0):

Se tiveres o máximo (ie, 10000 valores iguais a 1000000) a soma (10000*1000000 = `10000000000`) ultrapassa o limite disponivel em 32 bits (`2147483647`).

O tipo `signed long int` não é necessariamente adequado para essa soma.

Se podes usar C99, experimenta [`uint_least64_t`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.18.1.2) ou `/*un*/signed long long int`.

```
#include <inttypes.h> // auto include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    uint_least64_t soma1 = 10000;
    uint64_t soma2 = 10000; // pode haver computadores com C99 e sem este tipo
    unsigned long long int soma3 = 10000;
    signed long int soma4 = 10000;
    signed int soma5 = 10000;

    soma1 *= 1000000;
    soma2 *= 1000000;
    soma3 *= 1000000;
    soma4 *= 1000000;
    soma5 *= 1000000;

    printf("%" PRIuLEAST64 ", %" PRIu64", %llu, %li, %i\n", soma1, soma2, soma3, soma4, soma5);
    printf("sizeof (long)=%zu, sizeof (int)=%zu\n", sizeof (long), sizeof (int));
    return 0;
}
```

Podes ver o [código a correr no ideone.com](https://ideone.com/vu1yeg).

---

Se estás limitado a C89 (C90) experimenta calcular a média sem calcular o total...

```
média(N) = média(N-1) + (Val(N) - Val(N-1))/N
```

ou seja, em linguagem C

```
/* NÂO TESTADO! */
long oldtmp;
scanf("%li", oldtmp);
double media = oldtmp;
for (i = 1; i < N; i++) { /* inicia com i a 1 porque o primeiro valor já foi lido */
    long tmp;
    scanf("%li", &tmp);
    media = media + (tmp - oldtmp) / (i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Usando o gcc foi normal aqui. Acho também que no if de comparação você pode inverter para facilitar o entendimento. Onde se lê  if( (media/N) <  valores[i] ) poderia ser if( valores[i] > (media/N) ) .